# Brush Strokes showing multiple colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, fill

I'm trying to use a brush, employing the same color as the square to the left, but it's displaying multiple colors even though theres no fill. I tried to expand the appearance but it just selected all the colors on the layer. How do I fix this?
[image: Square & Brush Stroke]

Comment: Just to rule out obvious things, what sort of brush are you using?

Comment: A pressure brush. I'm using a wacom tablet. @SeanDuggan

Comment: Yes, but is there any shape to the brush? A stamp on it or other brush qualities? Or is this the default brush?

Comment: "Pressure" is a dynamic, not the name of a brush. Please what *type* of brush are you using? Bristle? Calligraphy? Scatter? Art? The tablet doesn't have any bearing on this. I suspect it may be a Bristle Brush with a hue dynamic set.

Comment: Oh sorry. It's just a calligraphy brush with adjusted pressure strokes @SeanDuggan

Comment: It sure looks like there is a fill applied. Have you selected the line and checked the *Appearance* panel? Also check if the layer or group has a fill applied. Would be easier to help if you have selected the object and included the *Layers* and *Appearance* panels.